# Where is the orange box?

Tags: support, review, 10k-tools, top-bar

I thought it already disappeared yesterday but then it appeared again. And now it seems gone again... Do someone knows what happened to the orange little box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indicator for pending reviews is only shown when the queues are above a certain length. I do not know the exact value off-hand for this site (it differs per site), but it should be around ten, and at the very moment there are only three review tasks so we are below that threshold and thus it is not shown.

You can still access the queues by clicking the word "review" (the box is just to signal with some urgency that you should do this).

Actually, in principle, the box not being shown should be the normal situation and it being shown can be seen as some kind of "alarm." It is just due to the tuning and other factors we live in an *almost* permanent state of "alarm."

So, relax, everything is fine, indeed things are better than usual. :-)

Comment: Makes sense, that is also why the orange box never appears in meta :).

Comment: I'm almost certain it's 10 for main, 3 for meta.